# (error) AWS as backend installing amplify libraries

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I am new to backend. Just starting to make a To-Do app in react and was just setting up amazon aws for backend. Using this site for reference ( https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react#initialize-a-new-backend ).

And at the point **Install Amplify libraries** I got stuck while i type `npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react` in root directory it shows me error everytime.[error pic][1] I am trying for a long but did not find any solution. Pls help me in this issue !!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrSeJ.png Here is the error i'm getting in command prompt

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^1.0.0-beta.2","@aw'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aakash~1Bansal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-09T11_41_43_000Z-debug.log

F:\Learning- tanay pratap\AWS\react-amplified>npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^1.0.0-beta.2","@aw'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aakash~1Bansal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-09T11_45_14_875Z-debug.log

F:\Learning- tanay pratap\AWS\react-amplified>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. 1st make sure your PC is connected to internet connection. Run:

```
npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli

npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

If possible don't minimize the window wait till everything is properly install.

This worked for me.

Still you are facing problems then reinstall node.js and then do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but after trying for long and not getting issue resolved, I shift from AWS amplify to google firebase for my project.